# How to read or sample stencil value from depth/stencil texture?

Tags: metal

Let's say I have a depth/stencil texture that has format `MTLPixelFormatDepth32Float_Stencil8` that I use as an attachment in a render pass and then I want to sample stencil values from that texture in a latter render pass.

Metal Shading Language Specification doesn't mention anything at all about this, only that depth textures need to be declared as `depth2d<T, access a = access::sample>` and for `depth2d` both `T sample(sampler s, float2 coord, int2 offset = int2(0)) const` and `T read(uint2 coord, uint lod = 0) const` return `T` where `T` will most probably be `float`.

So, my question is, how do I read or sample stencil values from this texture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [stencil texture view](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/WhatsNewiniOS10tvOS10andOSX1012/WhatsNewiniOS10tvOS10andOSX1012.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221-CH14-DontLinkElementID_77) of the depth/stencil texture with format `MTLPixelFormatX32_Stencil8`. Then, pass that texture view in to the shader where you want to read it. It operates as a `R8Uint` texture.

Note that not all devices support stencil texture views. They're supported for feature sets equal to or better than iOS_GPUFamily1_v3, iOS_GPUFamily2_v3, iOS_GPUFamily3_v2, tvOS_GPUFamily1_v2, or OSX_GPUFamily1_v2.

If it's not supported, you need to use a blit encoder to copy the depth/stencil texture to a buffer and then either use that buffer directly or copy it to a texture of a suitable format.

Comment: Totally forgot about texture views, now that I see them, it all makes sense. Thanks.